compilation of member functions using nested class types
I'm trying to understand nested structure declarations and why the following compiles. Is func only compiled after the full class definition is parsed or does this have to do with inlining at which point the definition of X is available ? Then why is it that the member variable instantiation does not compile ?
Is this always guaranteed to compile per C++ standard?
struct Y {
  // X x1; Does not compile
    void func() {
        X x;
        x.z = 12;
    }
    struct X {
        int z;
    };
};

int main() {
    Y y;
    y.func();
}


in a member function definition the class definition is available. Its the same for a plain member of Y

Yes, the body of the method is compiled after the whole class definition is known. So this is valid C++.

Inlining is only about performance, it doesn't affect program correctness.
The simple answer is that function bodies are processed at the end of the enclosing class (if the classes are nested, even functions in the nested class are processed at the end of the outermost enclosing class).

I don't know if I should post a separate question for this but why does     void func1(X x){} not compile. X technically is used outside of the function body in this case? But in any case why is there a difference in behavior between these use cases?

@user3882729 Yep, it's outside of the body. It's probably not allowed to make compiler developers' life easier.
